# Web site takes long load time to load after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, internet-connection

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10,my browsers take long time (more than 15 sec.) for opening  web sites or some times they don't open completely. But when site is opened once, the second time I open it loads faster.

Here is the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSCFaRwB5pQ).

Answer (score 1):

I think this fixes my problem:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It could be your ISP's DNS. Try using Google's ones: *8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4*

2) If that doesn't do the trick, try restarting your router.

3) You could also reinstall the firmware of your NIC.

4) For Firefox, type *about:config* on the url bar, write *pipe* in the search box, and enable *network.http.pipelining*